# Function pointer for an unknown template class

Tags: c++, com

I'm banging my head against the wall here... I wasn't sure how to word the title of this question since I'm not sure how to go about finding a solution for this.

I have a base template class (Component) that contains a map of all its instances for each component type (things like Position, Direction, Mesh). I'm having trouble formulating an "Iterate" function that will traverse the map and call a void member function (provided as an argument to the Iterate function) for each instance. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use function pointers, but all the examples I find online are for global functions or non-template classes.

Here's the base template class

```
typedef unsigned long uuid;

template <class T>
class Component {

public:
    static std::map<uuid, T*> IDS;
    static typename std::map<uuid, T*>::iterator Iterator;
    static T* Create(uuid fID) {
        Component<T>::IDS[fID] = new T(fID);
        return Component<T>::IDS[fID];
    };

    static void Iterate(); //how do I add in void function pointers?
    static bool ifExists(uuid fID);
};

template <typename T>
std::map<uuid, T*> Component<T>::IDS;

template <typename T>
typename std::map<uuid, T*>::iterator Component<T>::Iterator;

template <typename T>
void Component<T>::Iterate() {
    for(Iterator = IDS.begin(); Iterator != IDS.end(); Iterator++) {
        //This references the instance that performs the given function
        //(*Iterator).second
    }
}
```

and here's an example of a component used with the template.

```
class COM_Position {
    float x, y, z;
public:
    COM_Position(uuid fID);
    uuid ID;
    void Set(float fX, float fY, float fZ);
    void Display();
};

COM_Position::COM_Position(uuid fID) : ID(fID) {
    x = 0; y = 0; z = 0;
}

void COM_Position::Display() {
    printf("%lu : (%f, %f, %f)", ID, x, y, z);
}

typedef Component<COM_Position> Position;
```

How would I go about creating an iterate function that takes a function pointer as an argument that can be applied to each instance (for example, calling Display for each instance)? I'm hoping to be able to do something like this.

```
int main() {
    for(int ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++) {
        Position::Create(ii);
    }

    /*
    This is what I am aiming for; a clean iterator function
    Position::Iterate(Display());
    */
}
```

If this is not possible, I know I can simulate this with a macro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
template <typename T>
void Component<T>::Iterate(void (T::*method)() ) {
    for(Iterator i= IDS.begin(); i != IDS.end(); i++) {
        (i->second->*method)();
    }
}
```

And iterate:

```
Position::Iterate( &COM_Position::Display );
```

---

## Edit: Some neet overloads:

And with C++0x's variadic template you may use some generic methods. I didn't test it, but it looks promising:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void Component<T>::Iterate(void (T::*method)(Args... args), Args&&... params) {
    for(Iterator i= IDS.begin(); i != IDS.end(); i++) {
        (i->second->*method)(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
}
```

Most of functions and Functors can be used with:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void Component<T>::Iterate( F func ) { // using generic functor 
    for(Iterator i= IDS.begin(); i != IDS.end(); i++) {
        func(i->second->*method);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yay, you hit my 1k reputation ;-]

Comment: I'm not even kidding, you just answered what I've been trying to do for 6 hours. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I added some overload ideas. I'm happy. Now i can go sleep. Meh... is morning already.